# Meteor - using snychronised non-persistent / in-memory MongoDB on the server

Tags: mongodb, meteor, data-synchronization, minimongo

in a Meteor app, having real-time reactive updates between all connected clients is achieved with writing in collections, publishing and subscribing the right data. In normal case this means also database writes.

But what if I would like to sync particular data which does not need to be persistent and I would like to save the overhead of writing in the database ? Is it possible to use mini-mongo or other in-memory caching on the server by still preserving DDP synchronisation to all clients ?

### Example

In my app I have a multiple *collapsed*  threads and I want to show, which users currently expanded particular thread

> Viewed by: Mike, Johny, Steven ...

I can store the information in the *threads* collection or make make a separate *viewers* collection and publish the information to the clients. But there is actually no meaning in making this information persistent an having the overhead of database writes.

I am confused by the [collections documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html). which states:

> **OPTIONS**
>   *connection Object*
>   The server connection that will manage this collection. Uses the default connection if not specified. Pass the return value of calling DDP.connect to specify a different server. Pass null to specify no connection.

and

> ... when you pass a *name*, here’s what happens:
>
> ...
>   On the client (**and on the server if you specify a connection**), a Minimongo instance is created.

But If I create a new collection and pass the option object with `conneciton: null`

```
// Creates a new Mongo collections and exports it
export const Presentations = new Mongo.Collection('presentations', {connection: null});

/**
 * Publications
 */
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // This code only runs on the server
    Meteor.publish(PRESENTATION_BY_MAP_ID, (mapId) => {
        check(mapId, nonEmptyString);
        return Presentations.find({ matchingMapId: mapId });
    });
}
```

no data is being published to the clients.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: it's not possible.

There is no magic in Meteor that allow data being synced between clients while the data doesn't transit by the MongoDB database. The whole sync process through publications and subscriptions is triggered by MongoDB writes. Hence, if you don't write to database, you cannot sync data between clients (using the native pub/sub system available in Meteor).

Comment: Ok, this is unexpected. I was hoping this might be solved by implementing the _added_ , _changed_, _removed_, and _ready_functions. You can apparently [publish data coming from 3rd party APIs](https://blog.153.io/2016/06/09/meteor-cache-external-api/) And of course there is [redis-livedata](https://github.com/meteor/redis-livedata)

Comment: Indeed, you can use added, changed and removed to publish data in a fancy way that could be untied to mongoDB. This is an advanced use and maybe I misunderstood your question... Maybe you can update your question with the a description of the use case and set of tech you want to use ?

Comment: Hell Victor I edited my question and added an example. I would be very happy if you might provide a little bit more insight

Answer (score 0):

After countless hours of trying everything possible I found a way to what I wanted:

```
export const Presentations = new Mongo.Collection('presentations', Meteor.isServer ? {connection: null} : {});
```

I checked the MongoDb and no *presentations* collection is being created. Also, n every server-restart the collection is empty. There is a small downside on the client, even the collectionHanlde.ready() is truthy the **findOne()** first returns *undefined* and is being synced afterwards.

I don't know if this is the right/preferable way, but it was the only one working for me so far. I tried to leave `{connection: null}` in the client code, but wasn't able to achieve any sync even though I implemented the `added/changed/removed` methods.

Sadly, I wasn't able to get any further help even in the meteor forum [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/using-non-persistent-mongo/38634) and [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/pub-sub-data-without-mongodb-is-not-working/29262/10)